# Loop mixed linear model longitudinal time data assessing groups effect on the continous y variable

Tags: r, purrr, lme4, mixed-models

EDITED:

I'm trying to assess the effect of variables (e.g. presence of severe trauma) on a continous variable (here energy expenditure (=REE) in calories) over time (Day). The dataframe is called my_data. Amongst the variables

Following I would like to display the results using the mixed linear model for each assessed variable in one large file.

General concept:

```
REE ~ Time*predictor + (1 + Time | Case identifier)
```

(1) Starting creating the lmer model:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)
library(sjPlot)
library(lme4)

mixed.modelloop <- function(x) {
  lmer(REE ~ Day*(x) + (1 + Day | Studynumber), 
                        data=my_data, 
                        REML=FALSE, 
                        na.action=na.omit,
                        control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
}
```

(2) Then creating the predictors (x)

```
cols <- c(colnames(my_data))
```

(3) And then generating the overall purrr function:

```
output <- purrr::map(cols, ~ mixed.modelloop(.x) %>% tab_model)
```

(4) generating the file which should include all separate univariate mixed model analyses:

```
pdf(file="mixed linear models.pdf" )
output
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately currently after step (3) I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = my_data, na.action = na.omit, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Any idea on how to adapt the function to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `my_data` here? Seems it is mis-specified but it's hard to ascertain. It looks like you put your data where a random effect should be.

Comment: my_data is the name of the dataframe. changing it to 

````my_data %>%
lmer_models <- lapply(10:54, function(x) {lmer(REE ~ (1|.data[[x]]) + Day, data=my_data)})```  

results in the error message: 

! Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Error during wrapup: object 'dens1' not found
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Answer (score 0):

Formulas have special rules, you can't insert a string into them and expect them to work.

This should work, although you haven't given a reproducible example to test with ...

```r
mixed.modelloop <- function(x) {
    form <- reformulate(c(sprintf("Day*%s", x), "(1 + Day | Studynumber)"),
                        response = "REE")
    lmer(form,
         data=my_data, 
         REML=FALSE, 
         na.action=na.omit,
         control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
}
```